# Помогите, пожалуйста, перевести в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть чистый js, помогите пожалуйста перевести в jquery и подскажите как можно упростить появление исчезновение контейнера? сейчас делается путем наслоения, но неудобно использовать какие-то конкретные классы ксс для субменю, уж очень громоздкое js получается, как это реализовать на $(this)? без указания уникального класса субменю, пытался реализовать с помощью toggle, но ничего не получилось(

```
<script>
const drop_btn = document.querySelector(".drop-btn .drop-meka");
const tooltip = document.querySelector(".tooltip");
const menu_wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const menu_bar = document.querySelector(".menu-bar");
const setting_drop = document.querySelector(".setting-drop");
const help_drop = document.querySelector(".help-drop");
const setting_item = document.querySelector(".setting-item");
const help_item = document.querySelector(".help-item");
const setting_btn = document.querySelector(".back-setting-btn");
const help_btn = document.querySelector(".back-help-btn");
  drop_btn.onclick = (()=>{
    menu_wrapper.classList.toggle("show");
    tooltip.classList.toggle("show");
  });
  setting_item.onclick = (()=>{
    menu_bar.style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(()=>{
      setting_drop.style.display = "block";
    }, 100);
  });
  help_item.onclick = (()=>{
    menu_bar.style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(()=>{
      help_drop.style.display = "block";
    }, 100);
  });
  setting_btn.onclick = (()=>{
    menu_bar.style.display = "block";
    setting_drop.style.display = "none";
  });
  help_btn.onclick = (()=>{
    help_drop.style.display = "none";
    menu_bar.style.display = "block";
  });
```

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: нужна помощь с переводом на jquery

Comment: @Evgeny почитай про Делегирование событий например тут  https://learn.javascript.ru/events и не нужно будет чистый js переводить на jQuery и тебе понадобится пару строк кода для этого и 2 класса